# Django Generic Factory

Tags: python, django, django-models, factory-pattern

I have two questions that bother me. I'm facing an implementation where some document are related to different level of geodata and would like a factory to generate them. Let's see an example how I thought it may work:

```python
from django.contrib.gis.db import models


class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)


class Region(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)


class Law(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class CountryLaw(Law):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class RegionLaw(Law):
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

# Not sure this work but the idea is here
class LawManager(models.Manager):
    def create_law(text,geodata):
        if isinstance(geodata, Country):
            return CountryLaw(text=text, country=geodata)
        elif isinstance(geodata, Region)
            return RegionLaw(text=text, region=geodata)
        else:
            raise TypeError("Inapropriate geodata type")
```

I would like some factory method because I have some work to fill the fields of the "Law" that is common to all law, but this example doesn't show it.
My question are the following :

- Is there a better way to design Law objects ?
- Would such a manager work ? How could I access it ?

I search on google and stackoverflow for answer, but don't know what keyword to use and didnt found anything that could help me..

thanks for your help !

Comment: Why not make for every `Country` a "proxy" `Region`: a `Region` that represents the *entire* `Country`. Then there is only *one* `Law` type.

Comment: Suppose you have now also a model of `SubRegion` (like there is in my application), then at which level should I put the proxy ? I like your solution, but not sure that it fit my application

Comment: Well say you have a country `'Germany'`, then you have perhaps some regions (i.e. `'Bayern'`, `'Saxony'`, ...), but we can also add a `'Germany'` as region. It is not really a region, but we pretend that it is, we can even add a boolean or anything of the sort, if we would like to mark it a country. If you on the other hand want to use Subregions, we can add a subregion for `'Germany'` that is again `'Germany'`, etc. Nevertheless, another option could be to implement a *tree*-like structure, if the branching is rather arbitrary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there are several options here. The following "list" is not exhaustive, although it might perhaps provide a few ideas, and variants can be constructed based on these ideas.

## Leaving the models like it is

In that case we thus model it like:

```
+---------+ 1      N +------------+
| Country |----------| CountryLaw |
+---------+          +------------+
    | 1
    |
    | N
+---------+ 1      N +-----------+
| Region  |----------| RegionLaw |
+---------+          +-----------+
```

Here we thus constructed two `Law`s. Although we can of course superclass the two `Law`s, it means that each has its own type.

The advantage is that if the two have specific semantics, for example a `CountryLaw` should be handled quite differently from a `RegionLaw`, then that is easier to implement. Furthermore if a `CountryLaw` has specific fields, that are for instance not important for `RegionLaw`s (or vice versa), then we avoid wasting diskspace on `NULL` values (or other placeholders).

The downside is that if we for example want to query for laws that are part of `'Germany'`, we have to this in two steps: query for the `CountryLaw`s of germany, and query for the `RegionLaw`s of all regions of `Germany`. This can also easily get out of hand if you also have `SubRegion`s, `City`s, etc.

## Working with *Proxy* regions

Here we consider all `Law`s to be made for a specific `Region`, but the trick is that we construct a `Region` that acts like the entire country. So besides `'Saxony'` and `'Bavaria'`, we use a *virtual* region `'Germany'` that will represent the entire country.

We can then introduce a single `Law` model, that is attached to `Region`. If we frequently need to make the distinction between a region, and a country, we can add a field `is_country` that for example specifies if this is a "country proxy" or a real region:

```
+---------+
| Country |
+---------+
    | 1
    |
    | N
+-------------------+ 1      N +-----+
|       Region      |----------| Law |
+-------------------+          +-----+
| is_country : bool |
+-------------------+
```

The advantage is that we have only one `Law` object, and therefore the design is easier. Furthermore it is easy to query for the laws that map on a country (including or excluding regions).

The downside is that if country `Law`s and region `Law`s differ significantly, then this will result in an awful amount of checking (each time looking at whether the attached region is really a region, or a country), and furthermore it can result in a lot of *unused* fields. Furthermore if we enable more and more layers, we need to introduce more and more proxy objects. If we would for example would use three layers (`Country`, `Region`, `SubRegion`), then we need to construct for every country a "proxy" region (that contains a *proxy* subregion as well), and for every region, a *proxy* subregion. So if there are *n* countries and *m* regions, this would result in *2×n + m* proxy objects, which also results in *data duplication* (we repeat the name of the country/region multiple times, and if later a country or region is renamed, it will result in some pain to update all those proxies).

## Working with a *tree*-like structure

In case the number of levels can be large, or *dynamic* (in the sense that some "areas"* have subregions, whereas for others there is no region), or we want to handle all these levels in a *uniform* way, we could decide to use a *tree*-like structure.

Here we define a model, for example `Area`, an `Area` can have a `parent`, which is an `Area` as well, we can construct a *tree*-structure that way. For example something like:

```
class Area(models.Model):
    parent = ForeignKey('app.Area', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='children')
```

We can then attach to each `Area` zero, one or more laws. So the model looks like:

```
  ----
 N|  |1
+------+ 1      N +-----+
| Area |----------| Law |
+------+          +-----+
```

The advantage is that here we have *one* model for `Country`, `Region`, `Subregion`, etc. Furthermore we can implement a hierarchy exactly the way we want where for example some (small) countries have no `Region`s (like for example "*city states*" like *Vatican City*, *Singapore*, etc.). Furthermore the `Law` object will link to an "area"-like object. It is also easy to obtain the laws attached to a certain area.

A problem is however that it is hard to obtain *all* the `Law`s of a country, its regions, its subregions, etc. This can be handled however, for example by designing a many-to-many table that encodes the *transitive closure* of this tree structure: this many-to-many relation then will contain the links a country with *all* its regions, subregions, etc., but still that is not very elegant. It also means that all these `Area` instances are represented uniformly. Therefore if we want to add for example a list with official languages to the `Area`, all areas have "official languages", whereas probably most subregions simply would "inherit" the official language of their country.

## Using a `GenericForeignKey` in a `Law` object (Django feature)

Django also has a special sort of relation called the [**`GenericForeignKey`** [doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericForeignKey). This may look like a *great* feature for problems like this, but I would really advice to avoid such relations as much as possible.

By default Django add an implicit primary key to every model: if the developer does *not* specify a field with `primary_key=True`. Django will automatically add an `IntegerField` that will specify an identifier as primary key. It is thus reasonable to assume that *most* models have an `IntegerField` as primary key (in fact it israther *un-Django* to specify another primary key). We can also generate a list that maps every model to an integer: we could for example say that `0` maps to `User`, `1` maps to `Group`, etc.

This means that most model instances can be identified by two integers: one integer that specifies the model, and one that specifies the primary key of the corresponding model. For example `(0, 14)` is the `User` with primary key `14` (given we use the "lookup table" defined in the paragraph above). This is a powerful concept: we can thus use two database columns to store these integers, and each time let Django fetch the object. This is the idea behind a `GenericForeignKey`. We can thus define a `Law` like:

```
class Law(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    area = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

So this means that now our `Law` stores two real fields: a `content_type` and an `object_id`, and if we query for `some_law.area`, Django will fetch an object that corresponds with these two integers.

We thus could use this to refer to a `Country`, `Region`, `Subregion`, which can be useful in case we can refer to a variety of models. But there are a lot of disadvantages. The main problem is that such relations are usually very cumbersome in the case we want to use them in a query. Indeed: say we want to join our `Law` model with the `area` field. Then with which table should we join? The `Country`, the `Region`, the `SubRegion`? What if one `Law` refers to a `Country` whereas the other refers to a `Region`? So typically we can not `JOIN`.

Furthermore the model *itself* does *not* guarantee that the `GenericForeignKey` will always refer to an "area"-like object. It could refer to another `Law`, to a `User`, a `Criminal`, etc. So as a result you are responsible to write *sane* logic that will always make sure the relations make sense. Although this looks easy, it can be hard to maintain good *sane* relations. Most databases can not check whether the foreign key refers to a *valid* object, since there is no `FOREIGN KEY` constraint, since the "target table" is unknown.

Although there are a lot of drawbacks, in some cases a `GenericForeignKey` *can* be an elegant solution to certain problems, but one has to be careful.

Although there is - as far as I know - no generally accepted way to specify such relations in a diagram, it could look like this:

```
+---------+
| Country |
+---------+.
    | 1      .
    |          .
    | N          .
+---------+        . +-----+
| Region  |. . . . . | Law |
+---------+ 1      N +-----+
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for the time you spend answering my question ! The different model you propose are quiet complet and well documented about the advantage and drawback ! I think I will stick with my current model =) thanks once again